# How to separate two phrases in a grammatically correct way?

Tags: punctuation

In all stackexchange sites, there is an edit summary field provided when you try to edit a question or an answer. I find myself frequently writing there the following:

"edited title, added a tag"

or

"edited title, added two tags and edited body for clarity"

Here are my concerns:

1. Are the above two statements grammatically correct?
2. Should I replace the comma with a semicolon?
3. Are there any fullstops required in any of the two statements?

Comment: If you're concerned with "grammaticality", you might start by considering the fact that *there's no subject for the verb[s]* in your examples.

Comment: Commas are fine, semicolons are fine, end-stops (periods) are fine. The point is to say as briefly as possible, not as grammatically as possible, what you did & why. Your comments are understandable. That's all that's necessary. The character limit is about 160 for those comments, so write sparingly but clearly. I'd say "fixed title; added two tags; corrected spelling, punctuation, syntax, grammar for clarity", or whatever I did. I used two semicolons because the final list has commas.

Comment: @BillFranke Thanks for identifying the difference between comma and semicolon there.

Comment: Careful about separating lists containing elements including commas with semicolons.  I use that approach, but some others don't approve.  :-)

Comment: The above are not "statements" in the grammatical sense. They are fragments sufficient to convey the idea in a concise way. Rules of punctuation may apply as for usual sentences. Do *not* use a period (full-stop) because there's no sentence as such. Why do you think you need a semicolon?

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly grammatical in spoken English to omit a topic subject when it is clearly inferrable from context. e.g.,

> What happened to Thomas?
>   Got turned down again by Janice.

This convention is non-standard in most types of written English, but in proofreader's comments it is more than acceptable (to actually explicitly write the subject would sound odd).

Answer (score 1):

The examples given are grammatically non-standard, because the subject and a determiner are missing (it would have to be "*I* edited *the* title and added a tag" to be standard). But that's why a linguist would talk about "standard" and "non-standard", not "correct" and  "incorrect". Although they are non-standard ("not grammatically correct", if you like), they're absolutely fine as they are in the current context (and *far* better than the verbose "correct" versions).